# Angular losing scope in ng-form template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying this ,

```html
    <div ng-form="sadadPaymentForm" class="sadadPaymentForm"  ng-if="vm.isSadadEnabled" name="sadadPaymentForm"  validate-popup-form>
     <div ng-if="vm.isSadadEnabled">
       <div class="credit-debit-card-div" ng-include="'sadadTemplate'" ng-show="vm.view_tab == 'tab7'">
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <span ng-show="vm.view_tab=='tab7' && vm.isSadadEnabled">
     <button type="button" class="primary inline pay-now" id="paynowbtn" ng-disabled="!vm.checked3 || vm.sadadPaymentForm.$invalid" ng-click="vm.payByVoucher();" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="uaevent" analytics-eventcategory="Payment" analytics-eventaction="PayNow"
             analytics-eventlabel="Pay now">
               Pay by sadad
     </button>
   </span>
```

And , my template in another html file

```html
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="sadadTemplate">
    <input fieldlabel="Online Payment ID" type="text" name="onlinePaymentId" ng-model="vm.sadadpayment.onlinePaymentId"  class="form-control input-type-text"
                    ng-model-options="{ debounce: 100 }" validationKey-required="PaymentAdress1IsRequired" required maxlength="200">
  </script>
```

Here the `vm.sadadPaymentForm.$invalid` does not work but Indidual components validation works on blur on blur of input .

BUT , if I add vm to ng-form ,ie like this

```
    <div ng-form="vm.sadadPaymentForm" class="sadadPaymentForm"  ng-if="vm.isSadadEnabled" name="vm.sadadPaymentForm"  validate-popup-form>
     <div ng-if="vm.isSadadEnabled">
       <div class="credit-debit-card-div" ng-include="'sadadTemplate'" ng-show="vm.view_tab == 'tab7'">
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Here the `vm.sadadPaymentForm.$invalid` works but Indidual components validation fails on blur of input for eg, *TypeError: Cannot read property 'onlinePaymentId' of undefined*

Help me understand how can I make both individual validation and the final form validation work together.Angular Ver 1.5,cannot upgrade this now.Need a solution with 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out the issue , its basically a scope issue.

replaced

```
ng-if="vm.isSadadEnabled"
```

with

```
ng-show="vm.isSadadEnabled"
```

`ng-if` was preventing the DOM from rendering thus killing the scope variable vm itself

Answer (score 1):

Form `name` attribute should have `sadadPaymentForm` inspite of `vm.sadadPaymentForm`. Since you don't have form `name` specified correctly, validation is failing.

```
name="vm.sadadPaymentForm"
```

should be

```
name="sadadPaymentForm"
```

Comment: this I tried , but vm.sadadPaymentForm.$invalid fails.

Comment: why downvote? @sajanyamaha show me a plunker/stackblitz. I'm happy to help you further

Comment: I think the downvote is because your answer is the first thing I mentioned in my question which I tried already ,probably you missed it .

Comment: @sajanyamaha would you mind to provide plunker / stackblitz of problem statement please?